# Vlookup in external folder

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have an excel sheet with some product id codes

100-10R
23P901
......

I have a folder where the product images are stored. The beginning of the picture has the product code but the end might be different.

Does anybody know if it is possible to Vloopup a picture in an external folder bases on the product code?

Comment: On its own, No. VLookup is designed to work with data in the workbook, and not the filesystem. If you were to create a sheet with the name of every file in the external folder then yes you could, if you dont want to do this you'd need to use VBA

Comment: Thanks Nick. I know VBA basics. Is the code relatively complicated for something like this or should I look in to it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to look into the FileSystemObject, as this lets you look at stuff to do with the FileSystem.

I've made a quick example, although it might not do anything like what your trying to do as I wasn't completely sure. I hope it's fairly easy to understand.

The following code, if placed inside a module, will give you access to the "checkList" function in your worksheet.

The checkList function will loop through a cached list of file names from your specified folder, checking to see if the parameter "Name" matches any of the items stored in the list.

The cached list of files (the FileList collection) get populated once, the first time checkList is called by the loadList sub.

The loadList sub reads through your specified folder and adds all the file names to the collection.

```
' Global Variable, used to cache the filenames
Public FileList As Collection

' this function returns "" if no match was found, and returns the file name if found.
Public Function checkList(ByVal Name As String) As String
Dim Result As String
Dim Item As Variant

    Result = ""

    If FileList Is Nothing Then
        loadList
    End If

    For Each Item In FileList
        ' Performs a simple match on the filename, probably needs to be adjusted!
        If Item Like Name & "*" Then
            Result = Item
        End If
    Next Item

    checkList = Result

End Function
' populates the FileList collection
Public Sub loadList()
Dim FSO As Object
Dim Folder As Object
Dim File As Object

If FileList Is Nothing Then
    ' First Run, needs to be created
    Set FileList = New Collection
Else
    ' Should not happen unless you call it manually.
    Set FileList = Nothing ' Clear up the old list
    Set FileList = New Collection ' Create a new empty one
End If

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
' Change "C:\" to the location of the folder you want to search
Set Folder = FSO.GetFolder("C:\")

For Each File In Folder.Files
    ' Add the name to the FileList
    FileList.Add File.Name
Next

End Sub
```